# Java Servlet Repsonse Set Content Lenght For CSV

Tags: java, servlets, httpresponse, content-length

Requirements

Downlading a CSV File

Code

I have a csvFormattedString like

```
String csvFormattedString = "\"Column_One\",\"Column_Two\"\n\"Row_Col1\",\"Row_Col2\"\n";
```

This CSV String is written to the reponse print writer using

```
response.getWriter().write(csvFormattedString);
```

I have set the headers as application-force-download and have set the charcter encoding to UTF-8.

I would like to send the response length back to the user as well.

The `csvFormattedString.length()` does not seem to be correct as some my characters get truncated

Comment: What kind of framework/library are you using?

Comment: I am using no library to create the csv string, if you mean to ask that

Comment: I mean, what is the class of response object? How did you send this to the client? What's the class of the response rappresentation on the clientSide?

Answer (score 1):

`csvFormattedString.length()` counts the characters.
Use `s.getBytes("UTF-8").length` to get the number of bytes used for that string represented as UTF-8.

You have to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException` in order to use `getBytes(String encoding)`.